# Converting a cURL request to Node JS https request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, curl, httpresponse

I am running the following cURL request from terminal, which works.

```
curl 'https://api.bitclout.com/get-single-profile' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, /' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Ontel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537/36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en, zh-TW;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7' \
--data-raw '{"PublicKeyBase58Check":"","Username":"elonmusk"}' \
--compressed \
--insecure
```

Now I am trying to convert this code to Node JS javascript https request. My converted code is as follows:

```
const http = require('https');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  hostname: 'api.bitclout.com',
  port: null,
  path: 'get-single-profile',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    "PublicKeyBase58Check": 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv',
    "Username":"elonmusk"
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, res => {
    const chunks = []
  
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      chunks.push(chunk)
    })
  
    res.on('end', () => {
      const body = Buffer.concat(chunks)
      console.log(body.toString())
    })
});
```

However, when I run the aforementioned code I am getting the following error:

> events.js:292
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: socket hang up
> at connResetException (internal/errors.js:607:14)
> at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:23)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) Emitted 'error' event on
> ClientRequest instance at:
> at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {   code: 'ECONNRESET' }

Can anyone tell me what would be the code in javascript to get the same output as the cURL request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine.

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, /',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Ontel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537/36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept-Language': 'en, zh-TW;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7'
};

var dataString = '{"PublicKeyBase58Check":"","Username":"elonmusk"}';

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.bitclout.com/get-single-profile',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  } 
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply. are u sure it will be var request = require('request'); bcz it is saying can not find module request. Exact error output by terminal: Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#super-simple-to-use

You need to install the npm package in order to use it. npm i request

Comment: can I ask one more thing. If i want to return and store it in a json format what changes do I need to make to this code?

Comment: You can return the response body inside callback and parse it to json as required.

Comment: any possibility to modify the code snippet above to reflect this change plz? will mean a lot. thank u for the help. :)

Comment: if I do var profile = JSON.parse(body); return profile; within the callback function and then try to access it from output = request(options, callback); that wouldn't provide me access to json format. could u plz let me know what exactly to make change in the code to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot return the callback response outside the function. The standard is to follow the business functionalities in separate functions.
`function getResponse(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve(response);
    });
  });
}`
`async function triggerApi() {
  result = await getResponse(options)
  console.log(result.body);
}
triggerApi();`

Sample for you

Comment: Use async await functions, to get the responses.

Comment: But in the above code snippet the callback function is not triggered. where to call that? u can also edit the answer itself to reflect the change.